# Solving the following question without using lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus

This is an 11th and 12 grade problem which doesn't require multivariable calculus but i cant see any way of doing it without using  Lagrange multiplier.

Find the values of x; y for which $x^2 + y^2$ takes the minimum value
where $(x + 5)^2 + (y - 12)^2 = 14^2$.

I want a way which doesn't involve multi variable calculus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red circle is the circle $(x+5)^2+(y-12)^2 = 14^2$ and black circle is $x^2+y^2=r^2$. The minimum value is attained when the smaller black circle is tangential to the larger red circle. At this point, the distance between centers of the two circles is the difference between their radii, i.e., we have
$$\underbrace{\sqrt{(-5)^2+12^2}}_{\text{Distance between centers}} = \overbrace{14-r}^{\text{Difference in radii}}$$
This gives us that the minimum value of $r$ is $r=1$.

[image]

Similarly, to find the maximum value of $x^2+y^2$, the black circle should again be tangential to the red circle.

[image]

This gives us

$$\underbrace{\sqrt{(-5)^2+12^2}}_{\text{Distance between centers}} = \overbrace{r-14}^{\text{Difference in radii}}$$
This gives us that the maximum value of $r$ is $r=27$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the line through the origin that passes through the center of your defined circle region to optimize over, the minimum value of $x^2 + y^2$ will be the point on the line closest to the origin that intersects the circle you are optimizing over.

Comment: can you please elaborate by writing the answer

Answer (score 0):

Single variable way:

Note that y = $12 \pm \sqrt{14^2 - (x+5)^2}$

Then $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ becomes:

$g(x) = x^2 + [12 \pm \sqrt{14^2 - (x+5)^2}]^2$

Set $g'(x) = 0$

Multivariable way:

$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$

$0 = f_x = 2x \to x=0$

$0 = f_y = 2y \to y=0$

The possible solutions are x=0, y = whatever numbers you get from plugging in 0

and y=0, x = whatever you numbers get from plugging in 0

Then plug these 4 points into f(x,y). Whichever point/s gives you the minimum value is/are the answer/s.

Btw, [D > 0 and $f_{xx} > 0$ which means minimum](http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/multivariable/maxima_minima.html).

Read even more here. http://www2.math.umd.edu/~tjp/220%2007.3%20lecture%20notes.pdf

Comment: I don't want a multi variable calculus way i want something which comes under single variable calculus@BCLC

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay Added. That is not what you said though. You said no lagrange. It seems to suggest you forgot how to optimize multivariable functions without using lagrange.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay So how do you find my single variable solution?

Comment: @BCLCsince i am talking about the minimum should i also look for the second derivative test

Comment: I guess so @sayan

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to find the point on a circle with center C which is closest to a given point P.

If P is exterior to the circle, we can find the point where the line segment from C to P intersects the circle;
and if P is interior to the circle, we can extend the line segment from C to P until it intersects the circle.

In this case, $C=(-5,12)$ and $P=(0,0)$, and the line segment from C to P can be parametrized by $x=-5+5t, \;y=12-12t$; so substituting into the equation of the circle gives $(5t)^2+(-12t)^2=169t^2=14^2$, so $t^2=\frac{14^2}{13^2}$ and $t=\pm\frac{14}{13}$.

Taking $t=\frac{14}{13}$ to get the point where the line segment from C to P intersects the circle gives

$\hspace{.3 in}x=\frac{5}{13}, \; y=-\frac{12}{13}$.

(Equivalently, we could find the points where the line $y=-\frac{12}{5}x$ through C and P intersects the circle.)